# Exception in Collection.php line 1527: Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

i m getting error
Exception in Collection.php line 1527: Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.

```
public function index()
    {
        $response=array();
        $data = MyList::all();
        $response['id']=$data->id;
        $response['name']=$data->name;
        $response['password']=$data->password;
        $response['city']=$data->city;   
        return ResponseClass::prepareResponse(
                    $response,
                    'success',
                    ''
                );
    }
```

Comment: Because `$data` is a collection (multiple database rows), not a model (a single database row).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A collection doesn't have an ID, objects in this collection have IDs. So, you need to use `foreach` to iterate over the data. But in this case it's redundant, just do something like this:

```
public function index()
{ 
    return ResponseClass::prepareResponse(MyList::all(), 'success');
}
```